# Can a person with IQ of 130 contribute big contribution?

Tags: phd

I was tested and my IQ was at 130. I am currently PhD student studying mathematics. Will I be able to contribute to mathematics?

Comment: People ask a similar question to this on Psych&Neuro every so often. IQ scores don't work like this, it's not what they are validated for. Stop using IQ to compare you or anybody to anyone else.

Comment: Michael Faraday is one of the greatest scientists (an exquisite experimentalist) of all time. Though routinely considered to be a genius, admired by Einstein, Faraday attributed his enormous success to living in accordance with his simple motto: "Work. Finish. Publish." So maybe forget the IQ stuff and best of success!

Comment: I agree with Faraday. It is also a motto I will live by.

Comment: Have a read of the following blog by Terry Tao: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/does-one-have-to-be-a-genius-to-do-maths/

Comment: No, I haven't. Thank you for sharing this. I read it and I agree with everything that was mentioned.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is out of scope because mathematicians do not use IQ scores.

Comment: It is ok. I don't think it is useful as well.

Comment: I don't know but with such an IQ you should figure it out yourself.

Comment: There is always that doubt in your mind @Alchimista

Answer (score 5):

IQ means less than you think it does. Yes, you can contribute if and only if you study hard, work hard, and seek math insight into one or more specialty areas.

Excellence comes from hard work, nothing else. Plenty of "smart" people waste their lives. Plenty of average people excel because they don't let obstacles get in the way.

And don't neglect the need for working with others, even with those who *don't* have a 130 on some test.

There isn't a short cut. There isn't a magic bullet. Work.

Comment: Thank you for those wise words.

Comment: At the same time, I think you would need to have a certain minimum level of cognitive function to be able to contribute to mathematics. If you've got an IQ of 70 or less and you have difficulty spelling your own name, let alone writing academic texts, I think mathematics are probably not for you.

Comment: @nick012000 Sadly, an IQ of 70 does not keep politics out of reach ...

Comment: @EdV Can you give an example of someone with clinical intellectual disability (formerly called mental retardation) who has managed to achieve high political office? Neither Trump nor Bush count, despite assertions by their political opponents, because they have IQs of about 130, IIRC.

Comment: I was joking, but, given the horrible state of politics these days, I see no compelling reason that people with 70 IQ cannot go far in the field.